# Comparing arrays giving different results

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I have the following PHP code:

```
$a = "5";
$b = array("position"=>1);
var_dump("5" <= $b);
var_dump("5" <= "Array");
var_dump("Z" <= $b);
var_dump("Z" <= "Array");
```

the result is:

```
boolean true
boolean true
boolean true
boolean false
```

We know that array is converted to the string `array`. What's actually happening during the conversion? Why are the results different in the cases below?

```
var_dump("Z" <= $b); // (in this case array convert to string "array")
var_dump("Z" <= "Array");  // (in this case string "Array" )
```

But the result is different. Why?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? And what did you try?

Comment: this will be useful: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: What is your question? _'Why arrays are converted to "Array"'_? Ask php devs then. But really - that rule is not better and not worse than any other, so why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the manual [states](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> **Comparison with Various Types**
>
> array  | anything | array is always greater

When both operands are strings, string comparison rules are applied.

So no matter what the first operand is, `< array()` is always true

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following two expressions:

```
var_dump("Z" <= $b);
var_dump("Z" <= "Array");
```

In the first expression, you're comparing a string and an array. This comparison will always return `TRUE`. As the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) says, if any comparison is made between two operands where one of them is an array, the expression will always evaluate to `TRUE`. If both the operands are arrays, then the array with fewer members is considered smaller.

In the second expression, you're comparing `Z` to a literal string `Array`. In this case, the strings are first converted to  numbers before the comparison is made. This is usual math and the result is as expected. Since `Z` comes after `A` in the alphabet series, it'd return `FALSE`.